# ng2-datepicker set empty value

Tags: angular, ng2-datepicker

what i am trying to achieve is to set empty date field. By default it fills field with current date.

My template file

```
<ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="empty_date" [options]="options1"></ng-datepicker>
```

My .ts file

```
public options1: DatepickerOptions;
ngOnInit() {
this.options1 = {
      minYear: 2018,
      maxYear: 2100,
      displayFormat: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
      barTitleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
      firstCalendarDay: 1
    };
this.empty_date = {formatted: ''};
}
```

i also tried with `this.empty_date = "";`, `this.empty_date = null;` and `displayValue: ''` inside options1.

How can i set initial field value as empty?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/bleenco/ng2-datepicker/issues/12), just initialize your model to null. In the demo that they provide, I just transform from this:

```
export class AppHomeComponent {
  date: Date;
  options: DatepickerOptions = {
    locale: enLocale
  };
  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date();
  }
}
```

To:

```
export class AppHomeComponent {
  date: Date;
  options: DatepickerOptions = {
    locale: enLocale
  };
  constructor() {
    this.date = null;
  }
}
```

And worked ok:

[image: empty input value]

Comment: Strangely it still doesn't work. I did set constructor(){this.empty_date = null;}. It still shows today's date...

Comment: Can you paste your entire component?

Comment: I just used datepicker from bootstrap and it works the way i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I added a template reference on the tag `<ng-datepicker>` and the use `reset()` method on my component.

HTML:
`<ng-datepicker #date></ng-datepicker>`

COMPONENT:

```
@ViewChild('date') date: ElementRef;

resetDate() {
    this.date.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily clear selected date using ElementRef:

```
<ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="empty_date" [options]="options1" #date1></ng-datepicker>  

<button (click)="date1.displayValue=''">Clear Date</button>
```

**OR**

You can clear it from component also:

```
@ViewChild('date1') date1: ElementRef;

resetDate() {
    this.date1['displayValue']='';
}
```